# Why doesn't appending a path segment work using href="./other"?

Tags: html, url

I'm confused when it comes to how relative paths are calculated in urls.

When having a base url **without** a trailing slash ("example.com/a/b") I can't append a new segment with a relative path using only the new segment?

Why doesn't appending a path segment work using href="./c"?

When using href="../c" I get the expected result, a relative path one level up in the hierarchy. But what is the syntax to append a relative path even when the base url doesn't end with a trailing slash?

Just using href="c" replaces the last segment and using href="/c" removes all segments. The only relative option I have seem to be href="b/c" but then I have to repeat the last segment which doesn't always make it so easy. I wish href="./c" or something similar would work...

But perhaps "./c" is not correct because the dot refers to the "folder" which in this case could mean the last segment ending with a slash? But even then it should be possible to use some other syntax to accomplish the same.

Comment: Please show what you tried in code, i.e. what HTML and/or Javascript did you use?

Comment: @PeterB — There are 6 code examples showing what they tried in the question! (And one is repeated in the question title)

Comment: @Quentin I can't tell if that is `<a href="something">` (HTML) or `link.href = "something";` (JS), or something else being done in JS, so I am asking for clarification. Not everyone has to have to the same interpretation of something.

Comment: @PeterB – Since both would behave in exactly the same way, it doesn't matter which it is. (And you might start out from a position of explaining you don't understand the code examples rather than implying that they don't exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative URLs (which don't start with a `/`) are *always* computed from the last "directory" segment of the path. Any "file name" part is dropped. There is no way to change that with plain URL syntax.

You could do it by writing your own URL resolution code in a programming language of your choice.

Comment: Yes that's the thing, but are there any method to append even to a file-path? Some other syntax? Without repeating segments or using abs paths.

Comment: @AndreasZita — Quote "There is no way to change that with plain URL syntax."